# Aura:if use a function as expression

Tags: dynamic, aura-if

I wish to check a condition inside an aura:iteration. The condition should **be dynamically set** according to the current item in the iteration.

I'm trying to achieve the following :

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!c.myTestFunction(parameter)}">
    <!-- ... -->
</aura:if>
```

With the following in controller :

```
myTestFunction : function(parameter) { ... }
```

Of course this is not working. So my question is : is there any workaround to achieve this ? I would like not to update my iteration objects with a new property "toDisplay" that would require many updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be very useful sometimes, but you can't call methods like that (you can only invoke them with events) and you can't pass parameters to them. So in your case, I would recommend creating a component that you render in your iteration:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.myObjects}" var="obj">
    <c:yourComponent value="{!obj}" param="{!v.parameter}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

And your component could look like this:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="Object">
    <aura:attribute name="param" type="String">
    <aura:attribute name="isRendered" type="Boolean" access="private">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isRendered}">
        <!-- ... -->
    </aura:if>
</component>


doInit: function(cmp) {
    var rendered = //doSomethingWithParam
    cmp.set("v.isRendered", rendered);
}
```

Comment: repeatedly calling init in aura iteration looks like bad idea. Might slow down the page performance.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal It's JavaScript, so unless you've thousands upon thousands of items, the entire execution time is likely to be insignificant.

Comment: I can confirm what sfdcfox mentioned, we are already doing this eg. with a large grid, having no issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll do a wrapper component then! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have only two choices here:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!currentItem.display}">
```

Or

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!eq(currentItem.display, 'some value')}">
```

If you really need a function, you do need an attribute you can bind to, so you'll want to initialize the value as part of the attribute. You can't call a method with parameters, and you can't call a method period except in situations where it's allowed (primarily the `action` parameter of most components that have it, as well as event handlers like `onclick` or `pressed`), and even those don't accept parameters.